# How to append element from a multi-dimensional array to each element of another multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to append elements from a multi-dimensional list into a 2nd multi-dimensional list. Here is the code I wrote -

```
my_list = [
    [["b", ["a"], "c"], ["d", ["a", "b"], "e"]],
    [["j", ["a", "f"]], ["q"]]
]

ref_list = [[["q", "w", "t"], ["y", "u"]], [["s"], ["p", "k", "l"]]]


for a, b in zip(my_list, ref_list):
    for i, subl in enumerate(a):
        for ii, v in enumerate(subl):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                subl[ii] = b[i] + subl[ii]
                break        
print(my_list)
```

The output I am getting is -

```
[
    [["b", ["q", "w", "t", "a"], "c"], ["d", ["y", "u", "a", "b"], "e"]],
    [["j", ["s", "a", "f"]], ["p", "k", "l", "q"]]
]
```

It adds elements of 2nd list to the beginneing of 1st list. The output I am trying to get is of sort -

```
[
    [["b", ["q", "a", "w", "a", "t", "a"], "c"], ["d", ["y", "a", "b", "u", "a", "b"], "e"]],
    [["j", ["s", "a", "f"]], ["p", "q", "k", "q", "l", "q"]]
]
```

I want to add inner_most element of `my_list` after each element of `ref_list` instead of just adding it once in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight change to your code:

```
for a, b in zip(my_list, ref_list):
    for i, subl in enumerate(a):
        for ii, v in enumerate(subl):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                result = list()
                for element in b[i]:
                    result += [element]+subl[ii]
                subl[ii] = result
                break
        else:
            result = list()
            for element in b[i]:
                result += [element]+a[i]
            a[i] = result

>>> my_list
[[['b', ['q', 'a', 'w', 'a', 't', 'a'], 'c'],
  ['d', ['y', 'a', 'b', 'u', 'a', 'b'], 'e']],
 [['j', ['s', 'a', 'f']], ['p', 'q', 'k', 'q', 'l', 'q']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [
    [["b", ["a"], "c"], ["d", ["a", "b"], "e"]],
    [["j", ["a", "f"]], ["q"]]
]

ref_list = [[["q", "w", "t"], ["y", "u"]], [["s"], ["p", "k", "l"]]]


for a, b in zip(my_list, ref_list):
    for i, subl in enumerate(a):
        for ii, v in enumerate(subl):
            if isinstance(v, list):
                new_subl=subl[ii]
                subl[ii]=[]
                for j in b[i]:
                    subl[ii] +=[j] + new_subl
                break
```

Comment: This doesn't give the output OP needs. You're missing an `else` block. `mylist[-1]` is `[['j', ['s', 'a', 'f']], ['q']]` instead of `[['j', ['s', 'a', 'f']], ['p', 'q', 'k', 'q', 'l', 'q']]`

Comment: but he wants to add to the inner_most element. to the 3rd element

Comment: See the expected output. Your answer does not give that.